# What happened to bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, debugging

I have a manuscript which looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}               
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

[...]  
\cite{ref}  
[...]  
\cite{anotherref}  
[...]  
\bibliography{references}  
\bibliographystle{plain}
\end{document}
```

My .bib file, references.bib, looks like this:

```
@book{ref,
    title = {String theory and M-theory},
    isbn = {978-0521860697},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    author = {Schwarz, John and Becker, Katrin and Becker, Melanie},
    date = {2007-01-15}
}

@article{anotherref,
    title = {Locality problem for the Liouville field},
    volume = {274},
    issn = {0370-2693},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037026939291992I},
    doi = {10.1016/0370-2693(92)91992-I},
    pages = {323-330},
    number = {3},
    journaltitle = {Physics Letters B},
    author = {Balog, J. and Palla, L.},
    date = {1992-01-16},
}
```

For some reason, my manuscript does not compile properly. Instead of the inline references coming up as numbers, I get [**?**]'s. The bibliography does not appear at all.

What's very surprising is that even the [example](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/) in BibTeX's official website results in the same bug.

Another manuscript that had previously compiled properly for me, now produces the same error.

I am very puzzled by this. The bug is observed both in TeXmaker's Quick Build, and ShareLaTeX.

Anybody knows the cause of this bug?

Thanks!

P.S. Please feel free to vote to close this if it is off-topic.

Comment: You should use latex, then bibtex, then twice latex. Names of the programs may be slightly different.

Comment: There's a minor but crucial typo in your main program. If you replace `\bibliographystle{plain}` with `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and run latex, bibtex, and latex twice more on the main file, you'll be in business. Incidentally, you should encase `Liouville` in curly braces, i.e., write it as `{Liouville}`, to prevent the `L` from being converted to `l`. In the other bib entry, you may want to replace `M-theory` with `M\nobreakdash-Theory` since a line break between `M-` and `Theory` would seem to be quite undesirable.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, but my original manuscript spelt \bibliographystyle correctly, I made the error only while typing it here, so that's not the problem. Thanks for pointing out the nobreakdash and curly braces around Liouville.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying. Where should I use "LaTeX, then BibTeX, then twice LaTeX"?

Comment: In Texmaker for example, Tools --> pdfLaTeX (F6), then Tools --> BibTeX (F11), then twice Tools --> pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Probably, you have compiled using some automatic script before (texify, latexmk etc.)